# Is there a way to set smart/dynamic 'joinTo' output-files in Brunch?

Tags: javascript, html, configuration-files, brunch, multipleoutputs

First, I'll post an example how I "*think*" it may be defined in a Brunch configuration file:

```
files:
    javascripts:
        joinTo:
             # $1 = first sub-match in RegExp
            'app_$1.js' : /^app_([a-z0-9]*)/
            'vendor.js' : /^vendor/
```

Essentially I'm trying to figure out a way to have multiple outputs based on the name of each **"app_??????"** folders the Javascript files are stored in.

So if you have this folder structure, you would get the following output:

```
brunch_project/
    app_300x250/
        other.js
        app.js
        index.html
    app_728x90/
        other.js
        app.js
        index.html

    public/
        app_300x250.js
        app_300x250.html
        app_728x90.js
        app_728x90.html
        vendor.js
```

**Note**:
True, I didn't show in the configuration how the HTML would get renamed/merged the same as the JS files, but that's how I'd like it to work ideally. Bonus high-fives for anyone who shows me how it's done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only two variants, i'd suggest to just add files like `app_728x90.html` inside `assets/` directories. Then, create subfolders with resolutions inside `app/`. And use it in regexps.

If you need more than two variants, you can use JavaScript / CoffeeScript code to generate the `joinTo` clause like that:

```
joinTo = {}
for res in resolutions
  joinTo[res] = ///^app\/#{res}///

exports.config = files: javascripts: joinTo: joinTo
```

Comment: In my case it'll definitely be more than 2 files, so I'll likely use your suggested brunch config as Javascript (too unfamiliar to Coffeescript's syntax, for now!). Thanks!